# Error in Laravel pagination with complex select statement

Tags: php, laravel

I have the problem with pagination in laravel framework.
I built my query in this way:

```php
$auctions = Auction::where('status', '=', 1)
                   ->Where('minQuantity', '>', 0)
                   ->whereRaw('endTime > NOW()');

$auctions->selectRaw('*,' . DB::raw('IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM observed_auctions WHERE observed_auctions.idUser=' . intval($userId) . ' AND observed_auctions.idAuction=auctions.id)>0,\'true\',\'false\') as isObserved'));
```

Next, I get the result:

```
$auctions->paginate(15, ['name'], 'page', $currentPage);
```

It works pretty well until I want to find only observed auctions if I added where clause:

```
$auctions->where('isObserved', '=', true);
```

I get error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'isObserved' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `auctions` where `status` = 1 and `minQuantity` > 0 and endTime > NOW() and `isObserved` = 1)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Laravel determines the count (and therefore the last page) by removing your `select` bits and replacing them with a `COUNT(*)`. I'm not sure why it works this way but it's always been doing this. You can do manual pagination by manually determining the count but it's probably easier to do `simplePaginate` if you don't care about total pages

Comment: isObserved is an alias, not a column. You can't use it in a where clause

Comment: You are right. Thanks.